# Multiple process in WebKit (or equivalent)

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, qwebkit

In the Google Chrome each tab (or window/gui) is a different process (not only the tabs, but also plugins, extensions, etc.).

How can I make something like multi-process in Qt+WebKit?

> Note: No need to be multi-threaded or multiple-process, only something that can be equivalent

Each time I open a new window with `QWebView::createWindow` (or `QWebPage::createWindow`) I like to move (or create) the QWebPage/QWebFrame in a process (or thread) different.

How to do this? thanks

**[edit]**

What I like is that each `QWebView` (or `QWebPage`, `QWebFrame`, etc.) runs on a process (or something like that) separate (like google chrome).

**[edit]**

In QML, projects with QtQuick2.0 and QtWebkit3.0 use a process called qtwebprocess, this would be something useful for my project (my project is not QML)?

Comment: In the future, **your** questions would be *a lot* more `readable` if you didn't completely randomly *emphasize* words or `phrases`. Why is the note formatted as a quote? Why is some of it bold? Why the word "tabs" formatted as code? It is really much easier to answer your question if you just write it out, in english. Use `code markup` for actual code, not just for "words which are relevant to programming". I don't actually understand the "note" part. "there really needs to be multi-threaded"? multi-threaded *what*? And "just something like this", but "this" what?

Comment: My English is not good, that's better?

Comment: Yeah, much. :) (I edited out most of the bold though, to make it easier to read. Just use `code markup` for actual code (including class names and function names), and write everything else as plain text. Use **bold** or *italic* for *emphasis* only, not to highlight all the nouns. ;))

Comment: Grateful for the explanations +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to code it yourself. WebKit is not Chrome, and a lot of Chrome has nothing to do with WebKit. They basically just use WebKit as a HTML/CSS layout engine, but not most of the rest of WebKit.

If you want multiple processes, you will have to spawn multiple processes, each of which uses WebKit to render the specified page, and then set up the necessary inter-process communication for them to work together, and basically just code it yourself. WebKit is not a magic wand you can just wave to write your code for you.

Comment: In no time I said that Chrome and Webkit were the same thing.
I said "like" (something like that).

I asked if it is possible to create something separate processes or threads. It is an "idea" and not a "statement".

It would be possible to do something with QT that separates QwebPage (or Qwebframe)?

Comment: It is possible to do that, yes, but you'll have to do it yourself. Qt doesn't do it for you. It provides functionality for creating windows with tabs, and for drawing a web page, but it doesn't provide any out of the box functionality for rendering each tab in a separate thread or process.

Comment: In QML, projects with QtQuick2.0 and QtWebkit3.0 use a process called qtwebprocess, this would be something useful for my project? thank you